What are the "cutoff values" in Hybrid Branching?
In "Hybrid Branching" by Achterberg and Berthold, we have this line:

the number of subproblems that could be pruned due to branching on this variable, called the cutoff values

Can you explain to me what this is? What are "subproblems" in the context of a MIP tree? I assume that this refers to subtees that could be pruned? But how would you know this number ahead of time? How is it computed?

Maybe this link would be helpful.
